# How to truncate all tables that start with the same prefix - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, truncate, information-schema

With the code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'prefix%';
```

I can obtain all the tables that I want to truncate, but how can I execute the `TRUNCATE TABLE` function for the results of that `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute `TRUNCATE` from a `SELECT` statement. You could do something like

```
SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ',table_catalog,'.',table_schema,'.',table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'prefix%';
```

which would return a `TRUNCATE` statement for each table with the prefix. You could even look into using a stored procedure to execute each single row.